# Single ARMA estimation for multiple time series

Tags: matlab, prediction, ident

I have 365 days of hourly data (24points each) of a prediction error (realised -pred_day_before).

I want to model the evolution of the prediction error as an ARMA process.

Matlab System Identification Toolbox offers an ARMA estimation PER time series, whilst I have 365 time series (with supposedly the same characteristics).

How to estimate just one ARMA model for all of the 365 rows of 24 values?

Comment: I guess it depends on how you want to do the estimation. Do you wish to create an ARMA estimate for the year given an average for each day or do you want an ARMA estimate based on all values? However, are you sure that you do not want to apply a Kalman filter on this problem?

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer. I will rephrase the problem: every day before delivery, an estimation is made for the wind speed of the 24hrs the day-ahead.

I have the realized data (wind speed per hour) as well.
Based on these two historical data sets, I want to predict my prediction error in real-time for the coming hour, given my previous prediction errors. As this forecast is done daily, the pred'ion series start at 00:00 D+1 and end at 23:45 D+1. This is why I want to find just one ARMA process (single coeff) for the 365 historical days: to apply it on any given future day of 24h pred's.